# Transitioning Node Circle Colors in D3 Tree Visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, visualization, data-visualization

I have a problem where, when I collapse nodes, the colors of the stroke for other nodes also change (when they shouldn't).  The hint seems to be that the colors of the Tree branch being collapsed shift "down" to nodes in lower branches.

You can see the problem by clicking on "Node 1".  The result is that the colors of nodes 2 and 3 shift down to 4 and 5.  4 and 5 shift to 6 and 7, etc.

The interesting thing is that you reselect "Node 1" to expand the branch, all colors go back to their original and correct state.

NOTE: The tree visualization and source can be seen at: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/ed80661daf8e5fa89b85/

I have node related "circle" elements that I deal with in three blocks of code:

**BLOCK #1:**

```
      nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
          .attr("cx", horizontalTreeOffset)
          .attr("r", 1e-6)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue"
                                       : "#fff"; });
```

**BLOCK #2:**

```
      nodeUpdate.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 5.5)
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return color_hash[d.type]; })
          .style("stroke-width", 3)
          .style("fill", function(d) { 
            if(d._children)
              { return color_hash[d.type]; }
            else
              { return "white"; }
            }
          )
          .attr("type_value", function(d, i) { return d.type; })
          .attr("color_value", function(d, i) { return color_hash[d.type]; });
```

**BLOCK #3:**

```
      nodeExit.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6);
```

Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick sanity check: a given node in one branch (e.g. Node 4) is having its type_value attribute changed based on the collapsing of nodes in another branch (e.g. Nodes 1 and 2)...is this intentional?

Comment: No, not intentional.  It sounds like the issue as the colors are tied to types so, if the types are changing, it would make sense that the colors are, too.  May I ask where you're seeing this, as I can't seem to trap it in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, it's why I was asking...colors being tied to types. I am seeing this when using Chrome's Developer Tools and (right-click) inspecting element Node 4 while collapsing Nodes 1 and 2.

Comment: Found it!  It was in a totally different code block because of an ugly merge loop that I have to perform (because the API doesn't do the merge for you).  Will put it in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it...

The tree.nodes() method traverses the links and comes up with its own set of nodes.  This is totally different than the list of nodes passed into the program by the user, which contains all the traits for each node.  As a result, the original traits must be taken from the original node set and merged into the D3 generated nodes (that lack the traits).

When the code enters the update() method for every transition, the old code was iterating through the nodes and merging based on their index.  However, the index is now "shifted" due to the number of total nodes being less (because of collapsed nodes).  AND, the transitioned nodes have already gone through the process of having their traits assigned to them, so there's no reason to do so, again.

The new code to merge looks as follows...

```
      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      //nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
      if(!nodes[0].name){
        nodes.forEach(function(d, i){
          d.y = d.depth * 180;
          d.name = nodeSet[i].name
          d.type = nodeSet[i].type
          d.hlink = nodeSet[i].hlink
          d.rSize = nodeSet[i].rSize
        })
      }
      else{
        nodes.forEach(function(d, i){
          d.y = d.depth * 180;
        })
      };
```